# problema con selectpicker de bootstrap

Tags: javascript, firebase, bootstrap-4

Estoy trabajando con Firebase dataRealtime, select picker (), modals.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando hago clic en el icono de editar me muestra un modal con la información pre-cargada de la fila seleccionada para actualizar la información:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí es donde surge mi problema, ya que como se puede observar no carga el estado y municipio dentro de los selectpicker como lo hacen los demás datos. Y mis select no están vacios como lo muestro a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la estructura de la BD (Los datos son ficticios no se preocupen):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sólo ocupo el PHP para cargar datos en los selects (Estados y municipios no se encuentran en ninguna BD sólo es un archivo). En el form de AGREGAR USUARIOS hago la consulta a ese archivo y lleno los select.
Entonces solo obtengo el valor de los select (Un estado, un municpio seleccionado) y estos datos si van para Firebase. 
Antes de aparecer el modal-Form primero obtengo los valores de la consulta a la BD(Firebase)

```
  refB = db.ref("Beneficiarios/"+idBeneficiario);
  refB.on("value", function(snapshot) {
      console.log("Snap", snapshot.val());
  });
```

Para obtener el estado y municipio y de acuerdo a esto quiero establecer esos valores en los selects. Pero creo que el modal le gana a esto (no estoy seguro):

```
$("#jmr_contacto_estadoA").selectpicker();
$("#jmr_contacto_estadoA").selectpicker('val',estadoBenef);
("#jmr_contacto_estadoA").selectpicker('refresh');

$("#jmr_contacto_municipioA").selectpicker();
$("#jmr_contacto_municipioA").selectpicker('val',estadoBenef);
$("#jmr_contacto_municipioA").selectpicker('refresh');
```

Código HTML de select Picker:

```
<div class="form-group" id="lestadoA">
   <label for="jmr_contacto_estadoA" class="bmd-label floating">Estado *</label>
   <select class="form-control selectpicker" data-style="btn btn-link" id="jmr_contacto_estadoA" name="jmr_contacto_estadoA" title="Nada seleccionado">
      <option disabled>--Seleciona un estado--</option>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="lmunicipioA">
   <label for="jmr_contacto_municipioA" class="bmd-label-floating">Municipio *</label>
   <select class="form-control selectpicker" data-style="btn btn-link" id="jmr_contacto_municipioA" name="jmr_contacto_municipioA"  title="Nada seleccionado">
      <option disabled>--Seleciona un municipio--</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Código JS:
Esta función es la del evento .on('clic') de la fila, Aquí guardo los datos de la fila, lleno los selects, mando a traer los valores de la BD, coloco los valores en los inputs, pero al tratar con los select no sucede nada.
Espero me puedan ayudar.

```
table.on('click', '.edit', function() {
    $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    //data guarda los datos de la fila clicada en un array
    var data = table.row($tr).data();

    idBeneficiario=data[0];//Aqui se guarda la clave de nodo beneficiario
    //Funcion que carga los estados desde un arcivo PHP mediante AJAX
    cargaEstados2();

    //Obtener los datos de la base de datos del Nodo Beneficiario de acuerdo al idBeneficiario actual
    refB = db.ref("Beneficiarios/"+idBeneficiario);
    //Capturo los datos del nodo
    refB.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        console.log("Snap", snapshot.val());//Si Existen datos

        //En estas variables guardo la informacion de la BD
        appBenef = snapshot.val().apellidoPaterno;
        nombreBenef = snapshot.val().nombre;
        estadoBenef = snapshot.val().estado;
        apmBenef = snapshot.val().apellidoMaterno;
        municipioBenef = snapshot.val().municipio;
        organizacionBenef = snapshot.val().organizacion;
        empresaBenef = snapshot.val().empresa;


        //Aqui verifico que exitan estos datos
        console.log(estadoBenef);
        console.log(municipioBenef);

        //Coloca los datos obtenidos de la BD en los inputs del Modal del HTML
        benefNombre.value = nombreBenef;
        benefApm.value = appBenef;
        benefApp.value = apmBenef;
        benefEmpresa.value = empresaBenef;
        benefOrganizacion.value = organizacionBenef;

        //Aqui trato de mandar el estado y municipio actual a los inputs pero no se muestran
        $("#jmr_contacto_estadoA").selectpicker();
        $("#jmr_contacto_estadoA").selectpicker('val',estadoBenef);
        $("#jmr_contacto_estadoA").selectpicker('refresh');

        $("#jmr_contacto_municipioA").selectpicker(); 
      $("#jmr_contacto_municipioA").selectpicker('val',estadoBenef);
        ("#jmr_contacto_municipioA").selectpicker('refresh');

        }, function (errorObject) {
             console.log("La lectura de los datos fallo: " + errorObject.code);
        });
});//fin de edit table
```

Comment: El estado y municipio que te devuelve tu modelo es un string? y las opciones que estan en la vista son estáticas o las cargas del servidor, porque no están en el html pero tampoco veo que estén en la snapshot, tal vez es un error de transcripción porque por la imagen, ahí están, pero igualmente.

Comment: Si, String formado de esta manera: <option>Aguascalientes</option><option>Baja California</option><option>Otros_estados...</option> Estas opciones se cargan de servidor, es un archivo PHP aparte, estados y municipios no se encuentran dentro de firebase

Comment: ¿Dices que el string que almacenas en firebase es una etiqueta html? ¿Por que? digo puede que ahí esté el error, haz una petición del documento completo del beneficiario y adjuntalo a tu pregunta por favor. si hay datos sensibles censuralos, aunque me imagino que son dummies si la app no está en produción.

Comment: Ya edité la pegunta

Comment: Si estás utilizando PHP significa que tienes un backend, y nada más por curiosidad ¿por que utilizas un BaaS como firebase si podrías ejecutar una base de datos en local y escalarla como quieras sin tener que pagar un centavo? Digo si es por que es nosql siempre está mongo, o couchdb e incluso alguna de facebook, si es por el tiempo real, en realidad no es tan difícil implementar dropperjs o pusher o socket.io creo que todas tienen SDK para otras plataformas que no sean JS, solo es curiosidad jaja, un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que todo anda bien, recreé el ejemplo en una versión minima donde obtengo datos dinámicos de dos apis distintas, una para obtener los estados y otra para obtener el usuario, puedes visitar los endpoints si quieres, pero en conclusión todo anda perfecto.

Realmente no parece que haya nada mal con el código que muestras, lo único que tengo que agregar es que realmente no necesitas invocar los selects cada vez que los actualizas con datos o lo que sea, si ya tienen la clase en el html no hace falta nada mas (no confundir con refresh).

Por lo que para mi hay tres opciones:

1. Estas importando mal las librerías
2. El valor del string en el documento del usuario (snapshot) no es estrictamente igual al que hay en las opciones del select.
3. Estas escribiendo literalmente `("#jmr_contacto_municipioA").selectpicker('refresh');` notese que falta el signo `$` (dollar) y no estarías llamando el refresh, pero esto no explica porque no funciona en los dos, solo debería afectar uno.

Mira mi ejemplo funcionando perfectamente, fíjate en que orden están las librerías y compara los datos json de las respuestas para que puedas ver que te está faltando.

```js
fetch("https://raw.githack.com/dantaex/ciudades_mexico/master/states_mexico.json")
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => {
  res.states.forEach(item => {
    $("#jmr_contacto_estadoA").append(`<option>${item.name}</option>`)
  })
  $("#jmr_contacto_estadoA").selectpicker('refresh')
})

$("#get").click(e => {
  fetch("https://api.npoint.io/5f910e3002f1318f0c04")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res)
    $("p span").html(res.username)
    $("#jmr_contacto_estadoA").selectpicker('val',res.state);
    $("#jmr_contacto_estadoA").selectpicker('refresh');
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  background: white;
  color: #323232;
  font-weight: 300;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.15/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.15/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<div class="form-group" id="lestadoA">
  <p>Usuario: <span>undefined</span></p>
   <label for="jmr_contacto_estadoA" class="bmd-label floating">Estado *</label>
   <select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn btnlight" id="jmr_contacto_estadoA" name="jmr_contacto_estadoA" title="Nada seleccionado">
      <option disabled>--Seleciona un estado--</option>
   </select>
   <button id="get" class="btn btn-light mt-3 d-block">Obeter usuario</button>
</div>
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda, un saludo.